# Why is the background of my list view revealed?

Tags: android, listview, background

Some of the main contents and all section headers don't fill their list view row. Any idea, what can be the problem?

[image]

```
date_section  layout: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#A1A1A1"
    >
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:id="@+id/post_date"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle = "normal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="#A1A1A1"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Cell layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- hi new  changes -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background"
    >




    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/post_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle = "normal"
                android:textColor="#202020"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="test"
                 />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:id="@+id/post_execerpt"
                android:textColor="#888888"
                android:textStyle = "italic"
                android:textSize="14dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:lines="2"
                android:text="test"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try setting the textview width to "fill_parent"

Comment: Just like hsnepen mentioned, make sure the list items' width fill_parent.

Comment: @hsnepen its already set to fill_parent.

Comment: I am editing the question and adding the layout code as well.

Comment: Do you change the parameters of any `TextView`s in code other than setting their texts?

Answer (score 0):

In your `date_section.xml` file, add this line to the `TextView`

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Good Luck

Comment: Can you try removing the `android:textStyle = "normal"` line ? This is just a guess !